# Why does using a comma in Haskell function application cause different types?

Tags: haskell

I have run these haskell function in ghci then got those output, but i dont know how to explain it. What is the difference between g(x,y) and g(x y) and how the yield that output.

```
*Main> let  j g (x, y) = g(x,y)
*Main> :t j
j :: ((a, b) -> t) -> (a, b) -> t

*Main> let  j g (x, y) = g(x y)
*Main> :t j
j :: (t1 -> t2) -> (t3 -> t1, t3) -> t2
```

Comment: `g (x y)` means that `x` is a function, that you first perform function application with `x` the function and `y` the parameter, and then pass that result to `g`.

Comment: Hi, you appear to be a Haskell beginner. I'd strongly reccommend reading [LYAH](http://learnyouahaskell.com/chapters) to completion for beginner programmers before diving into questions. This question is answered in LYAH.

Comment: also be sure to check out `let  j g (x, y) = (g x y)`.

Comment: @AJFarmar seconded, except for "to completion .. before".  Asking questions is an important part of learning, even when using a "textbook".  But I agree that Lama might benefit from reading a few chapters.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> What is the difference between `g(x,y)` and `g(x y)` and how the yield that output.

Well Haskell has - compared to the gross of programming languages - an "unusual" syntax (compared to very common languages like C, Java, etc.) how to describe function applications.

`f x` is a function application with `f` the function, and `x` the parameter. The parentheses are not necessary (in contrast to for example programming languages like C, Java, C#, etc.), however they may be included. Therefore `f(x)` is interpreted as `f (x)` and since `(x)` is simply `x`, the two are equivalent.

With that in mind if we look at `g (x y)` we see *two* function applications: `x y`, and `g (x y)`. In a programming language like Java, this would look like `g(x(y))`. `g`, and `x` are thus both functions (where the "output type" of `x` should be the same as the "input type" of `g`). We perform function application with `x` the function and `y` the parameter, and the result is a parameter in a function application with `g` the function.

Haskell also has *tuples*. For example `(4, 2)` a 2-tuple. `(x, y)` is a 2-tuple as well: `x` is the first element, and `y` the second. If we thus write `g (x, y)`, then we perform a function application with `g` the function, and `(x, y)` (a 2-tuple) the parameter. So that means that `x` has type `a`, and `y` has type `b`, then `g` has type `(a, b) -> c`.

With that in mind, we can derive the signature of functions, for example:

```
j g (x, y) = g (x,y)
```

We see here that `j` has "two" parameters (in Haskell all functions have *one* parameter, the result of that function takes then another parameter), so we start by describing the signature of the function as:

```
j :: a -> b -> c
g :: a
(x, y) :: b
g (x, y) :: c
```

Since `(x, y)` is a tuple, we specialize the type of `(x, y)` as `(d, e)`, so that means that the signature changes to:

```
j :: a -> (d, e) -> c
g :: a
(x, y) :: b ~ (d, e)
g (x, y) :: c
x :: d
y :: e
```

(the tilde `~` stands for the fact that the two types are the same)

Since we call `g` with `(x, y)` as parameter, we know that `g` is a function. The input type is the type of the parameter `(x, y)`, so `(d, e)`, whereas its result type is here the type of the result of `j g (x, y)`, hence `c`, so we derive that `g` has type `(d, e) -> c`, so that means that:

```
j :: ((d, e) -> c) -> (d, e) -> c
g :: a ~ ((d, e) -> c)
(x, y) :: b ~ (d, e)
g (x, y) :: c
x :: d
y :: e
```

Then all constraints are satisfied, hence the type of `j` is:

```
j :: ((d, e) -> c) -> (d, e) -> c
```

I leave deriving the type of `j g (x, y) = g(x y)` as an exercise.

Comment: Can you please explain the type of this function
*Main> let  j g (x, y) = g(x y)
*Main> :t j
j :: (t1 -> t2) -> (t3 -> t1, t3) -> t2

Comment: Same as ML, Idris, Agda, etc. Maybe unusual in the grand scheme of things, but far from unique!

Comment: Clear in such type of expression. Could you please describe type signature of :
h f = foldr ((:) . f) [ ]

Comment: @LamaMadan: I suggests you ask a new questions, since, well, this is a new question :).

Answer (score 5):

In Haskell (unlike in C-derived languages), function calls are not indicated by parentheses after the function.  Instead, Haskell treats any two consecutive expressions as function application, so that `(x y)` reads as "the function `x` applied to argument `y`".

Also unlike C-derived languages, Haskell has native support for tuples:  `(x,y)` reads "the tuple of `x` followed by `y`".

Combining these together, Haskell will treat `g(x,y)` as "the function `g` applied to the tuple `(x,y)`, which is similar to how it reads in C-like languages.  However, this similarity is misleading:  C-like function calls require the parentheses to indicate the function call, while in Haskell they only delimit the tuple.

From your other example, `g(x y)` reads "the function `g` applied to the result of (function `x` applied to argument `y`)".  In a C-like language, `x y` would be a syntax error, but Haskell recognizes it as a function application.